# Como fazer que um atributo do DTO seja validado apenas quando enviado?

Tags: java, rest, validação, spring-mvc, spring-data

Estou desenvolvendo um método PUT com Spring MVC para alterar uma entidade que tem diversos atributos (ex: nome, idade, gênero).

Porém gostaria que somente aquilo que for enviado no corpo da requisição fosse validado (PUT parcial ou tipo um PATCH), por exemplo:

- **URL:** PUT /api/v1/potatos
- **BODY:** `{"name": ""}`
- **RESULT:** Gera exceção porque o atributo `nome` não pode ser vazio, mas não critica a falta do atributo `idade` por exemplo.

---

Abaixo eu tenho um exemplo do que estou tentando fazer:

**CONTROLLER**

```
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/potatoes", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class PotatoController {
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> potatoRegister(@RequestBody @Valid PotatoDTO potatoDTO) {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();

        response.put("message", "everything alright");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(response.toString());
    }
}
```

**DTO**

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Null;

public record PotatoDTO (
    @NotBlank(message = "crisp")
    String name,

    @NotNull(message = "chips")
    Integer age
) {
}
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi, se voce quer que `age` seja opcional, não deveria usar a anotação `@Null` seguido de alguma validação de número inteiro?

Comment: Não vai criticar a ```idade``` enquanto o campo ```nome``` for ```null```.  Digamos que, de baixo dos panos, o que ocorre é um ```if``` aninhado. Se o primeiro já for ```false```, nem passa pelas outras condicionais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui fazer essa validação sem adicionar o `@NotNull` ou `@Null`, mas para isso eu tive que separar a propriedade em uma classe e adicionar o `@Valid`:

```
public record UserDTO(
    @NotBlank(message = "cannot be null or empty")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 150, message = "size must be between {min} and {max}")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-zÀ-ú ]+", message = "must contain only letters")
    String name,

    @NotNull(message = "cannot be null or empty")
    @Past(message = "must be before the current date")
    LocalDate birthDate,

    @NotBlank(message = "cannot be null or empty")
    @Size(min = 11, max = 11, message = "must have {min} characters")
    @CPF
    String cpf,

    @NotBlank(message = "cannot be null or empty")
    @Email(message = "is invalid")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 80, message = "size must be between {min} and {max}")
    String email,

    @Valid
    UserRelationDTO relation
) {
}
```

Desta forma é possível validar apenas se a propriedade for enviada no JSON.

**Sem a propriedade:**

```
{
    "name": "Bigois",
    "birthDate": "1996-02-04",
    "cpf": "***055*****",
    "email": "bigois@oc.com.br"
}
```

**Com a propriedade:**

```
{
    "name": "Bigois",
    "birthDate": "1996-02-04",
    "cpf": "***055*****",
    "email": "bigois@oc.com.br",
    "relation": {
        "id": "413e7099-3244-4a1f-b3df-b7500cddfbb2"
    }
}
```